# Terraform update access policies

Tags: automation, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am facing a problem and workflow related to terraform to automate the creation of storage account, key vaults and access policies.
What I am trying to achieve is as follow:

I have a storage-account that runs with a for_each loop:

```
//==================================================
// Automation storage accounts
//==================================================
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage-foreach" {
  for_each                 = var.storage-foreach
  access_tier              = "Hot"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  location                 = var.location
  name                     = each.value
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.tenant-testing-hamza.name
  depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault_key.client-key]


  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}
```

this storage account resource, loops through this variable to create the storage accounts

```
variable "storage-foreach" {
  type    = map(string)
  default = { "storage1" = "storage1", "storage2" = "storage2", "storage3" = "storage3", "storage4" = "storage4"}
}
```

so far everything works smoothly. Than I wanted to add those storage accounts object id to my key vault access policy, as follow:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "storage" {
  for_each           = var.storage-foreach
  key_vault_id       = azurerm_key_vault.tenantsnbshared.id
  tenant_id          = "<tenant-id"
  object_id          = azurerm_storage_account.storage-foreach[each.key].identity.0.principal_id
  key_permissions    = ["get", "Create", "List", "Restore", "Recover", "Unwrapkey", "Wrapkey", "Purge", "Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Sign", "Verify"]
  secret_permissions = ["get", "set", "list", "delete", "recover"]
}
```

so far everything works just fine while creating the resource, I have all the access policies in place. But, If I try to remove, for example the `storage1` from my variable, the storage account get deleted and the access policies related to that specific storage, which is good.
And here the main issue I am facing. If I try to add again the same storage in the variable and run a terraform apply , what happen is that the 3 policies still existing they get removed and the access policy for the storage account get created. If I do one more time `terraform apply` the logic get inverted, it will delete the first storage account access policy and add the other 3.

I can't find a solution to just update my access policies accordingly to the element I have set in my variable.

Comment: I'm not clear what is the error you meet. Please describe more clearly.

Comment: I found my issue. it was a misconfiguration between the access policy declared in my resource key vault, and another resource that was generating those access policies with a loop.

Comment: If you don't mind, I have an 'issue that I would like to address'. My key vault has the 'Purge protection enabled', I have some storage accounts encrypted with some key. When I want to delete one of those storages, I get an error that I don't have 'purge and delete permissions' which I do. But I realised that this error happens because while destroying the storage account, the access policy  (for that storage) in my key vault, get deleted before the storage, so it throws an error. Is there any solution to this? `depends_on` does not work in my case

Comment: It's another issue, so you need to create another question. We can't discuss it in the comment. Please provide more details with the new question so that I can give help.

Comment: If you solve this issue yourself, please add the answer.

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.